# 3D interactive web-deploy 3d-modeling

Tags: animation, 3d, interactive, 3d-modelling

I am looking for a dependable workflow that will allow interactive, 3D models deployed on the web (i.e.: low-poly, low-res). The question is how to target and programmatically animate **parts** of the whole (like the individual fingers on a hand)--not just rot, scale,move the model but rather the parts. This was quite dependable via Collada exported to Papervision + Flash, very much more difficult to achieve with Away 3D and Flash. Can't really achieve this with Processing and .OBJ import ( no real Collada support there at all)--Should I bite the bullet and try the openGL + JavaScript options?(the performance + access seems so much less optimal) .Not for commercial work, btw.
Please offer suggestions (though I don't have access to Maya or fancy modeling software; Blender is what 've been using).
I appreciate any thoughts on this, and THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Unity?
Its very possible to export your model/scene onto a web viewable format through the unity Player.

For creating low poly models, you could have a simple workflow that is fairly automatic by using some polygon reduction/simplification tools.

Most of these tools rely on simplification algorithms are based on iteratively collapsing edges and thereby merging vertices together. A cost is associated to each edge based on the curvature of the connecting edges. A large priority Q is maintained and is used to iteratively collapse edges of minimum cost.

Also Hughes Hoppe's algorithm for Progressive Meshes is often used to visually select the Level of detail that is desired.

There are plenty of implementations of this available for reference on the internet.
How ever most are only for educational purposes. If you want to use this technique for production code, you're better off studying the algorithms and creating a more efficient implementation yourself.

If you're using Unity:
This tool already has this implemented within Unity engine. Its available for purchase on the unity Asset store.
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/149948-Cruncher-Polygon-Reduction-Plugin-for-Unity-Pro

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

[GLGE](http://www.glge.org/), a WebGL framework, supports Collada models and animations according to this [GLGE blog entry](http://www.glge.org/2011/01/).  The demo is [here](http://www.glge.org/demos/frankiedemo/), and one of the models/animations is at http://www.glge.org/demos/frankiedemo/sheep.dae.

I'm not sure how easy it is to set this all up.  When I looked at this a while ago it looked like you could control things with some XML.  You'll have to snoop around the website, its forums, source code and docs to see how things fit together.